# Where to create web service or wcf service for accessing SQL Server 2012 data

Tags: web-services, wcf, sql-server-2012

As I am new to web service and WCF too I don't know where to create web service (or WCF) for accessing SQL Server 2012 data.

Is there any tool to create web service like Visual Studio 2010 (maybe but I don't know)? If yes then how to create it in Visual Studio suggest any solution.

If there is any code of web service or WCF service to access SQL Server 2012 data then please post or link it or if possible send the zip of it

Comment: When you say "web service", do you mean an ASMX service? Don't use those. ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: ok but how to used and create wcf service or ASP.NET Web API to access mssql server data using this.
As I already mentioned in my qtn that I am new to WCF I dont know How to create it and where to create it. If any answer then plz suggest
Thanx...

Comment: Is Google down, or are you banned from using Google? There are **tons** of excellent tutorials out there on how to create a WCF service - seriously, you can't miss them, if you search!

Comment: My google not down but i think u have some sophisticated link to share..
Thanx

Comment: You don't need the perfect link to get started. Start by writing a program (maybe a console application) to just get the data you want from SQL Server. Then, write a simple WCF service ("hello, wcf"). Then, put the two together.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use this framework [Nelibur](https://github.com/Nelibur/Nelibur). Just modify an example according to your needs.

Official site: [Nelibur.org](http://nelibur.org)

Here is an idea to get you started

```cs
public sealed class ClientProcessor : IPostWithResponse<CreateClientRequest>,
                                IGetWithResponse<GetClientRequest>,
                                IDelete<DeleteClientRequest>,
                                IPutWithResponse<UpdateClientRequest>
{


       public object GetWithResponse(GetClientRequest request)
       {        
          string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
          using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
              using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE Id=request.Id", connection)) {
                 connection.Open();
                 Client client = ...read from database here...
               }
          }
   return client;
  }

... other methods ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplet example to learn WCF step by step with backend,

[WCF Service to Insert,Delete and Update](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/468354/WCF-Example-for-Inserting-Deleting-and-Displaying)